# Cannot figure out why this curly brace is giving out an error

Tags: java

```
public String checkIn(Book b) {
  for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
   if (b.equals(books[i])) {
    if (checkedOut[i] > 0) {
     checkedOut[i]--;
     return "Checked in!";
    }
    else {
     return "All of our copies are already checked in.";
    }

   }
   else {
   return "Book not found.";
   }
  }

 }
 }
```

The last curly brace is where I get the error. What's odd is that it recommends i remove it yet it still gives out the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Count your braces...

Comment: Hi Aladdin, you have aded extra brace remove last one.

Comment: Every opening brace { should have only one corresponding ending brace }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one too many braces. Remove the last one. I would recommend formatting your code, as it will make it easier to read and fix problems like these in the future.

```
public String checkIn(Book b){
    for(int i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
        if(b.equals(books[i])){
            if(checkedOut[i] > 0){
                checkedOut[i]--;
                return "Checked in!";
            }else{
                return "All of our copies are already checked in.";
            }

        }else{
            return "Book not found.";
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

If you are not using an IDE such as [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) or [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/), I would recommend using one as they will help with your errors.

Answer (score 1):

Few Mistakes.

1.) `One curly brace is extra` in the last.

2.) Also add `return statement` at the end of function.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below code

```
public String checkIn(Book b) 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) 
  {
   if (b.equals(books[i])) 
   {
        if (checkedOut[i] > 0) 
        {
         checkedOut[i]--;
         return "Checked in!";
        }
        else 
        {
         return "All of our copies are already checked in.";
        }

   }
   else 
   {
        return "Book not found.";
   }
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code

```
public String checkIn(Book b)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
   {
      if (b.equals(books[i])) 
      {
          if (checkedOut[i] > 0)
          {
             checkedOut[i]--;
             return "Checked in!";
          }
         else 
         {
            return "All of our copies are already checked in.";
         }

     }
     else 
     {
         return "Book not found.";
     }
  }

 return "something";
}
```